# javascript - intersections with different prototypes

Tags: javascript

I have this constructor:

```
 var Song = function(side, name, index, duration, author, lyrics) {
     this.side = side;
     this.name = name;
     this.index = index;
     this.duration = duration;
     this.author = author;
     this.lyrics = lyrics;
     globalLyrics.push(this);
   };
```

Then I created instances of songs:

```
  var song1 = new Song('Mithras', 'Wicked', 1, '3:45', 'Me and The Plant', 
           ["politicians", "politician", "politics", "telling", 
           "lies", "lie", "to", "media", "the", "youngsters", 
           "young", "elders", "time", "that", "passes", "pass", "by", 
           "oh", "no", "lie", "detector", "detection", "souls", "as", 
           "far", "illusion", "goes", "all", "sinners", "sin", "around", 
           "sun", "earth", "atom", "atoms", "mind", "angels", "angel", 
           "prophet", "prophets", "martyr", "knives", "elder", "detect", 
           "shit", "flies", "fly", "meat", "is", "knife", "and", "death", 
           "life", "I", "am", "gonna", "going", "cast", "a", "sacred", 
           "circle"]);


   var song2 = new Song('Mithras', 'Requiem', 11, '3:25', 'Me and The Plant', 
         ["you", "want", "wanna", "get", "some", "and", "what",
         "is", "a", "sad", "song", "move", "along", "then", "trip",
         "on", "are", "try", "trying", "to", "belong", "oh", "no", "it",
         "the", "go", "up", "like", "king", "kong", "come", "coming",
         "down", "goes", "minor", "key", "unlock", "unlocks",
         "moans", "moan", "all", "integrity", "just", "breaks", "bones",
         "I", "wait", "for", "in", "line", "that", "will", "bring", "me",
         "home", "wrong", "feels", "feel", "right", "wretchedness",
         "wretch", "among", "amongst", "so", "warm", "never", "be",
         "alone", "because", "cause", "have", "these", "life", "short",
         "break", "politicians"]);
```

Later I added a method to the prototype:

```
Song.prototype.playLyrics = function() {
         for(var i = 0; i < this.lyrics.length; i++){
             console.log (this.lyrics[i]);
    }
 };
```

Lets say I have a user input (later on a form):

```
  var input = ["politicians"];
```

And an intersection function:

```
  function intersection (input, lyrics){
       return input.filter(function(n){
       return lyrics.indexOf(n) != -1
       });
   }
```

QUESTION:

Since `intersection()` is not part of the Song `prototype`, how do I make a function to return the NAME of the song -`this.name` relative to the lyrics `this.lyrics` that has the most intersections with the user input?

In short, given the above example, I want to enter `var input = ["politician"]` and `return //Wicked`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to make the function to search song's name by lyrics ?
**1. Using song as argument**

```
function intersection(input, song ){

}
```

**2.You can store all the songs by global variable like**

```
var songList = [];

// Push the song on the list when you make the song
var song1 = new Song(...);
songsList.push(song1);

// Using songsList to make your search

function intersection(input){
 // Find the name of song by loop the songList
}
```